# Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException

Tags: flutter, file-upload

When I upload .zip file or .docx ,it deos not work ,but when I choose .c files they work fine
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Failed to decode data using encoding 'utf-8', path = '/storage/emulated/0/New Text Document.zip'

```
  File _file;
  Future upload() async {
    if (_file == null) { return; }
    String path = _file.path.split("/").last;
    var pdf = _file.readAsStringSync();
    var url ="http://192.168.1.112/flutter/upload_file.php";
    var data = { "path": path, "pdf": pdf };
    var response = await http.post(url, body: data);
  }

  Future pickFile() async {
    final myfile = await FilePicker.getFile();
    setState(() {
      _file = File(myfile.path);
    });
  }
```

Here is my php file I tried to use readAsBytesSync and it gave me error

```
 <?php
    include 'connection.php';
    include 'register.php';
    
    $pdf = $_POST['pdf'];
    
    $file_name = $_POST['path'];

    file_put_contents("uploads\\".$file_name, $pdf);
?>
```

Comment: because the file is inside a zip file

Comment: But I want to upload anytype of files not just .c or .txt plzz help mee I have a project

Answer (score 0):

```
_file.readAsStringSync()
```

This assumes that your file is plain text. A `*.c` file most likely is. Neither zip, nor doc nor pdf files are.

What you need to do is [read your file as bytes](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File/readAsBytesSync.html):

```
var contents = _file.reasAsBytesSync();
```

Now, I don't know what your API expects to get, so I cannot really help you with how to get the bytes transferred. But this is the way to go.

Comment: Exception has occurred.
_CastError (type 'Uint8List' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)

Comment: File _file;
  Future upload() async{
    if (_file==null){ return;}
    String path=_file.path.split("/").last;
    var pdf=_file.readAsBytesSync();
    var url ="http://192.168.1.112/flutter/upload_file.php";
    var data ={"path":path,"pdf":pdf};
    var response =await http.post(url,body:data);
  }
  Future pickFile() async{
  final  myfile=await FilePicker.getFile();
    setState(() {
      _file=File(myfile.path);
    });
  }